# OLS Estimator Function

Tags: r, function, na, lm

I am trying to rebuild the lm() function in R as an exercise. Here is the code I am currently using (you'll see that the only return() value in the function is b, but I will change that once I get the whole function fixed):

```
OLS <- function(y,X){
    df <- nrow(X) - ncol(X);
    b <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% y);
    se_whole <- as.numeric(sqrt((t(y - X %*% b)%*%(y - X %*% b))/df));
    se_beta <- se_whole * solve(t(X) %*% X);
    return(b)
    }
```

When I run the function, all I get for b is a column vector of NAs. Why would this be? I presume it has something to do with my definition of b within the function, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Perhaps someone could enlighten me!

Thanks!

Comment: What `y` and `X` are you giving to the function?

Comment: It works for me: `with(mtcars, OLS(mpg, cbind(1, wt)));
lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)`

Answer (score 3):

I applied your code and it seems to work for me. However, why do you return only b? Are you not interested in the s.e. as well?

The following site derives the OLS in R manually step by step. Overall the code seems to be the same.

http://economictheoryblog.com/2016/02/20/rebuild-ols-estimator-manually-in-r